# Weird recursion in setting the default file manager in antix/icewm

Tags: file-manager, icewm, antix

I've installed antiX Linux 19.3, and I want to change the file manager - for the first user and by default - to something other than the annoying rox (sorry, I just don't like it). So, I've installed pcmanfm, went to the Control Center pressed "Preferred application" and got a dialog with paths of `.desktop` file. Ok, so far so good. The file manager one is: `deskto-p-defaults-follow-fm.desktop`, suggesting the setting is actually taken from elsewhere.

Now, that `.desktop` file runs:

```
desktop-defaults-run -fm --follow
```

there's a matching `desktop-defaults-set`, but - if I run that one, I get the dialog I saw before. So it's as though there's a recursion without anybody choosing a file manager.

I then looked into `desktop-defaults-run`, and it seems to be looking for a file-manager-related `.desktop` file, which itself runs `desktop-defaults-run -fm --follow`. Unless I've mis-parsed the script (which I may have - it sources some more scripts when it starts).

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ desktop-defaults-run -fm --follow
```

is used for launching the same file manager as whatever is handling the desktop icons (if nothing handles the desktop icons, then it defaults to rox)

Simply use the `desktop-defaults-set` program and change the file manager to point to a different .desktop file (in your case, /usr/share/applications/pcmanfm.desktop)

You could also use spacefm included in antiX.

Comment: Is there some benefit to spacefm over pcmanfm, or is it just because it's bundled with the installation?

Comment: spacefm is an old fork of pcmanfm which gives you the power to completely customize ALL of the interface, including right-click menu. If you are not into customization and know pcmanfm well, use it instead. antiX includes 3 file managers, the same as it includes 4 window managers: choice.